# Python exit/terminate script in Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

**use-case -**
To terminate the script if the switch condition is not met.

**Code:**

```
class Menu():  
    def item1(self):
        print("Price of Pizza is Rs.80")
    def item2(self):
        print("Price of Burger is Rs.100")
    def item3(self):
        print("Price of Chicken fires is Rs.150")
    def item4(self):
        print("Price of Cool Drink is Rs.30")
    def item5(self):
        print("Price of Noodles is Rs.50")    
       
    def price(self,no):
        item_price="item"+str(no)
        method=getattr(self,item_price,lambda :print('Invalid'))
       #method=getattr(self,item_price,lambda :exit())
        return method()

d=Menu()
d.price(6)
print("I don't want to see this")
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid
I should not see this line
```

**Desired output**

Script doesn't run if the condition is not met.

**What I've tried:**
I've update the code as below, but it doesn't work.

```
method=getattr(self,item_price,lambda :exit())
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the indentation..2.  Why should you not see the output line "I should not see this line"? 3. I don't get the "invalid" line you get.

Comment: Try now, I fixed the indent, you should also now get "invalid"

Comment: 1. Indent fixed
2. I want script to exit if the switch is not met.
3. You should now get 'invalid'

Comment: You can see code here - https://pythongeeks.org/switch-in-python/  , Please see the last one.